# Minusing 3 characters from the end of a string in Java

Tags: java

I have a string oCustomerOrderNumber which I am passing a value into iCustomerOrderNumber. I would like to remove the last 3 characters from this iCustomerOrderNumber but unable to get this to work. Error I get is that it does not like the -.

Code:

```
 oCustomerOrderNumber = iCustomerOrderNumber.trim() -  
 (iCustomerOrderNumber.length() -3);
```

Example. ICustomerOrderNumber is 1234567 I want oCustomerOrderNumber to be 1234.

Comment: you should use the substring method. trim() doesn't return a length, but a trimmed version of a String

Comment: `yourString.substring(0, yourString.length() - 3)`.

Comment: There is no minus operator for strings in Java

Comment: What should I use instead of -?

Answer (score 3):

> For getting a portion of a string you can use substring method and
>   here you can define from where until where you want to fetch from any
>   String:

```
iCustomerOrderNumber.substring(0, iCustomerOrderNumber.length()-3);
```

Comment: you should at least provide some explanation of what you do, why you do it, and what the difference with the original code is

Comment: @Stultuske yeah it was a fast send. hehe :-)

Comment: And all in all you can not remove anything from String, since String is immutable class, but you can create a new modified string from existed one, as Mehdi showed.

Answer (score -4):

oCustomerOrderNumber = iCustomerOrderNumber.substring(0, (iCustomerOrderNumber.length() -3));

Comment: This is nothing but a copy-paste of a (part of a) previously posted answer